# CentOS 6.5 - How to upgrade HAProxy?

Tags: https, haproxy

Can someone tell me how to upgrade HAProxy from 1.5.4 version to the latest version?

I'm using a virtual machine CentOS 6.5.

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy up to 1.5.4 is available for Centos via the package repository, so to get a newer version you will have to compile from source.

To upgrade to the latest version, you could follow [these instructions](https://github.com/swisstxt/rpm-haproxy) to make your own installable package.

In summary:

```
sudo yum install rpmdevtools pcre-devel
rpmdev-setuptree

sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
sudo yum install openssl-devel

wget http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/src/haproxy-1.6.9.tar.gz
mv haproxy-1.6.9.tar.gz ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/

git clone git://github.com/bluerail/haproxy-centos.git
cp haproxy-centos/conf/* ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
cp haproxy-centos/spec/* ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/

cd ~/rpmbuild/
rpmbuild -ba SPECS/haproxy.spec
```

The RPM should be available in `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64`. You can install it like:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh RPMS/x86_64/haproxy-1.6-9.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following `yum` command:

```
yum update haproxy
```

According to a quick [repo search](http://centos-packages.com/6/package/haproxy/), this should update to HAProxy 1.5.4. Prove the version change with:

```
haproxy -v
```

Comment: The problem is, RHEL for some reason stopped building haproxy packages past 1.5. CentOS7 has tops 1.5.18, since then haproxy advanced 3 minor versions (4 when they release 1.9).